# MySql command parameters with quotes

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to insert rows to a MySql Database through my c# application (using Connector/Net 8.0.11). I'm using command parameters to pass the values because - in my understanding - i don't have to care about any kind of special characters. Please find a simplified code example below.

```
MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO testtab(TestCol1,TestCol2) VALUES(@test1,@test2)", Con);

Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", "12'34");
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test2", "56");

Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But the single quote in "12'34" leads to an exception:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '34','56')' at line 1"

I know that i could simply not use parameters at all, and just double the quote inside my value string... but i have built similar apps using Connector/ODBC and they work fine. Can you please help me to find the trick with Connector/Net?

Comment: im more concerned about that `near '34','56'` part. it looks like MySQL connector is some how inlining the query without properly escaping it. Can you try to put a sql injection query in there and see if it works? like `("@test2", "1'; DELETE FROM testtab WHERE ('1' = '1");`

Comment: @PaulF my mistake

Comment: The escaping result of `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString("12'34")` is `12\'34` BUT shouldn't it be `12''34`?

Comment: @Steve still getting exception like `...near '; DELETE FROM testtab WHERE (\'1\' = \'1')'`. I assume the connector is not exactly inlinig it.

Comment: oh dear... after the comment of @fubo i turned off SQL mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES... and guess what - it works. But this is kind of killing me because in my customers database i can not change the sql mode. And still, Connector/ODBC works fine... i hope i dont have to rework the whole app, i'm not the biggest fan of odbc :|

Comment: @m.denis it looks like it is inlining it. Basically doing a string escape then inlined it. IMO it should send it the parameter way.

Comment: @m.denis According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html you have to call `Prepare()` before adding the values. Does it help?

Comment: @Progman wow dude that works! Prepared statements were just a performance thing to me, i actually never considered them... i wish i paid attention to that sentence: `Another advantage of prepared statements is that, with server-side prepared statements enabled, it uses a binary protocol that makes data transfer between client and server more efficient.` It is still weird that i have to use them, but the trick works! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really appreciate your help ladies and gentlemen - and special thanks to Progman, your comment solved my problem.

**I'll now answer my own question to sum it up. There are 3 possible solutions:**

The whole issue is related to the SQL mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES. One solution could be turning off that particular SQL mode.

fubo mentioned in his comment:

> The escaping result of `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString("12'34")` is `12\'34`

It is weird but the SQL mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES struggles with the escape strings of parameter values (imo this is a bug in Connector/Net since Connector/ODBC works fine). Another solution could be using Connector/ODBC.

The final trick for me was Progmans comment:

> According to [dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/…](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) you have to call Prepare() before adding the values.

This is more like a workaround, but if you use SQL mode NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES and command parameters together, you have to call `Prepare()` before calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`. Please note that - unlike the example in the developer guide - i couldn't call it before adding the parameters (you'll get an exception), and i added `IgnorePrepare=false` to the connection string. I assume the reason why this works is because it changes the data transfer between client and server:

> Another advantage of prepared statements is that, with server-side prepared statements enabled, it uses a binary protocol that makes data transfer between client and server more efficient.

Here is the code snippet that works for me:

```
//add IgnorePrepare=false to the connection string
MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Port = 3306; Database = param_test; Uid = ***; Pwd = ***; SslMode=none; IgnorePrepare=false");
Con.Open();
MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO testtab(TestCol1,TestCol2) VALUES(@test1,@test2)", Con);

Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test1", "12'34");
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test2", "56");

Cmd.Prepare();  //calling it after Adding the parameters works fine
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```